# evaluate $\int_0^{\infty}\frac{x^a}{x^2+1}dx$ for $a\in(0,1)$

Tags: contour-integration

I am stuck on this complex analysis homework problem :( here is my attack so far:

If I integrate around a keyhole contour, I can show that $$\int_0^{\infty}\frac{x^a}{x^2+1}dx=\frac{2\pi i}{1-e^{2a\pi i}}\sum_{w\in\{i,-i\}}RES(\frac{e^{a\log z}}{z^2+1},w).$$  Now, luckily the poles in this integrand are simple, so it's easy enough to find: $$RES(\frac{e^{a\log z}}{z^2+1},i)=\frac{e^{a\pi i/2}}{2i},$$ while $$RES(\frac{e^{a\log z}}{z^2+1},-i)=\frac{-e^{-a\pi i/2}}{2i},$$ and adding these fellas together we get $\sin(a\pi/2)$ by Euler's i.d. So it goes $$\int_0^{\infty}\frac{x^a}{x^2+1}dx=\frac{2\pi i\sin(a\pi/2)}{1-e^{2a\pi i}}.$$ But where to go now? The integral on the left is real, while I have my doubts about the term on the right.

Have I made a mistake, or there's some further trick I don't see? (I'm almost certain it's the former, since I'm an expert at mistakes but an amateur at finding them). Anyways, I would appreciate any help, or advice on this problem. Thanks!

Comment: Factor out an $e^{\pi a i}$ from the denominator

Comment: @ Frank W. Oh I see! haha wow I'm dumb, thank you so much!!

Comment: While a useful technique, that doesn't actually solve the issue here. The expression written down is indeed not real.

Comment: @jmerry yes but it made it more clear what the issue with my solution was, also thank you for your answer as well!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trick to this one? You've got the wrong residues. We have to use the same branch of the function in calculating the residues that we did in setting up the integral. Specifically, since we run $\arg z$ from $0$ to $2\pi$, we should write the two zeros of the denominator as $i=\exp\left(\frac{\pi i}{2}\right)$ and $-i=\exp\left(\frac{3\pi i}{2}\right)$. The residues are then $\frac1{2i}e^{a\pi i/2}{2i}$ and $\frac{-1}{2i}e^{3a\pi i/2}$.

That leads to a factor of $e^{a\pi i}$ in the numerator. Divide through by it, the denominator becomes $i$ times a sine, and it all comes out real.